# display button upon typing input react

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I want to be able to type into my input fields, and then have a button show up beside it upon typing that says submit edit. right now, I have a button that always is there, but I want it to only show up upon typing. this is all in react btw. so far, I have tried `jquery`, but react doesn't like it.

here's the whole page, to avoid any confusion of what I am doing and where my stuff is located.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/TourPage.css";

class TourPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
      isLoading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/getResults")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          myData: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  deleteById = (id) => {

    console.log(id)
    axios
      .post(`/deleteDoc`, {id: id} )
      .then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked")
        window.location = "/tour"
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);

  })
}

editById = (id, siteLocation, Services, cnum) => {

  console.log(id, siteLocation, Services, cnum)
  axios
    .post(`/editDoc`, JSON.stringify({id: id, location: siteLocation, Services: Services, cnum: cnum}),{
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "Application/json"
      }
    } )
    .then(() => {
      console.log(id, " worked")
      window.location = "/tour"
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the errors here
      console.log(error);

})
}
  render() {
    // You can handle the loader part here with isLoading flag. In this case No data found will be shown initially and then the actual data
    let { myData, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <table id="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>siteLocation</th>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>cnum</th>
        </tr>
        {myData.length > 0
          ? myData.map(({ location, Services, cnum, _id }, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder={location} name="location" id="location" /> </td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder={Services} name="Services" id="Services" /> </td>
                <td><input type="text" placeholder={cnum} name="cnumhide" id="cnumhide" /> </td>
                <td><input type="hidden" placeholder={cnum} name="cnum" id="cnum" /> </td>
                <button
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    this.deleteById(_id);
                  }}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
                <button
                 onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var siteLocation = document.getElementById('location').value
                  var Services = document.getElementById('Services').value
                  var cnum = document.getElementById('cnum').value
                  this.editById(_id, siteLocation, Services, cnum)
                }}
                >
                  Submit Edit
                </button>
              </tr>
            ))
          : "No Data Found"}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

const script = document. createElement("script"); $('input').keyup(function(){
  if($.trim(this.value).length > 0)
      $('#location').show()
   else
      $('#location').hide()
});

export default TourPage;
```

thanks 4 the help in advance.

Comment: Apparently, the check for the presence of text occurs after they start typing it. Obviously, in this case, the button will always be visible. Moreover, you are trying to get a button as `$('#location')`, but there is no button with this ID

Comment: Use onChange() onfocus() onfocusout() methods to maintain state of the variable responsible for the submit button

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat could u show me how?

Comment: @developerg1000 can you use functional component?

Comment: you don't need jquery to achieve what you want.

Comment: @IamL how would I do it otherwise? Could you show me?

Comment: @Danial I am not sure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onfocus()` in the text element. If you want to hide the button, use `onfocusout()` or in case if you want to track only after input has changed, use `onchange()` event

```
    ...
    //class function
    onTyping =()=>{
        this.setState({
            showSubmit:true
        })
    }

    ...
    //render part
    render(){

    ...
    //input which you want to track typing
    <input type="text" onfocus={()=>this.onTyping()} placeholder={location} name="location" id="location" />
    ...
    //element submit button
    {this.state.showSubmit &&  <button
                 onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var siteLocation = document.getElementById('location').value
                  var Services = document.getElementById('Services').value
                  var cnum = document.getElementById('cnum').value
                  this.editById(_id, siteLocation, Services, cnum)
                }}
                >
                  Submit Edit
                </button>}
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that helps you,

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;
const Test = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value.length > 0)
      setShow(true);
    else
      setShow(false)
  }
  return ( <div>
    <input type = "text"
    onChange = {
      (event) => handleChange(event)
    }/>
    {show && < button > Submit changes now! </button>} 
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render( < Test / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to avoid jquery and continue using your react class component to achieve this.

Map over `state.myData` to render each item with an input and a button.

Use the array index with the input's `onChange` event callback to add the `inputValue` into the correct array item's object within state.

Use the array index with the button's `onClick` event callback to get the item from `state.myData` before sending it to the server.

If there is an `inputValue` for the item, you can conditionally render the button.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class TourPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          myData: res.data.results
        });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  handleChangeInput = ({ target }, index) => {
    const newData = [...this.state.myData];
    newData[index].inputValue = target.value;
    this.setState({
      myData: newData
    });
  };

  handleSubmitEdit = (index) => {
    const item = this.state.myData[index];
    // submit the edit to the api
    console.log(
      `Clicked on 'submit edit' for ${item.name} with value ${item.inputValue}`
    );
  };

  render() {
    let { myData, isLoading } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
      return "loading...";
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {myData.map(({ name, status, species, inputValue }, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <p>{`${name} - ${species} - ${status}`}</p>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeInput(e, index)}
                value={inputValue || ""}
              />
              {inputValue && (
                <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmitEdit(index)}>
                  Submit Edit
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TourPage;
```

[image: Edit practical-worker-ku3jz]

---

If you wanted to have an input per field within each row, you could make some small changes and save your edits to the item's state within a nested object.

Then you could check if there was anything inside that row's edits object to conditionally show the submit button per row.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import isEmpty from "lodash.isempty";
import pick from "lodash.pick";

class TourPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          // here we create an empty 'edits' object for each row
          myData: res.data.results.map((d) => ({
            ...pick(d, ["name", "status", "species"]),
            edits: {}
          }))
        });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  handleChangeInput = ({ target }, index) => {
    const newData = [...this.state.myData];
    const { value, name } = target;
    newData[index].edits[name] = value;
    this.setState({
      myData: newData
    });
  };

  handleSubmitEdit = (index) => {
    const item = this.state.myData[index];
    // submit the edit to the api
    console.log(`Clicked on 'submit edit' for ${item.name} with edits:`);
    console.log(item.edits);
    console.log("Updated item: ");
    const { edits, ...orig } = item;
    const newItem = { ...orig, ...edits };
    console.log(newItem);
    // Once saved to api, we can update myData with newItem
    // and reset edits
    const newData = [...this.state.myData];
    newData[index] = { ...newItem, edits: {} };
    this.setState({
      myData: newData
    });
  };

  showButton = (index) => {
    const { edits } = this.state.myData[index];
    return !isEmpty(edits);
  };

  render() {
    let { myData, isLoading } = this.state;
    if (isLoading) {
      return "loading...";
    }
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {myData.map((row, index) => {
            const { edits, ...restRow } = row;
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                {Object.keys(restRow).map((col) => {
                  return (
                    <td>
                      <label>
                        {col}:
                        <input
                          name={col}
                          value={edits[col] || restRow[col]}
                          onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeInput(e, index)}
                        />
                      </label>
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
                <td>
                  {this.showButton(index) && (
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmitEdit(index)}>
                      Submit Edit
                    </button>
                  )}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default TourPage;
```

[image: Edit distracted-star-dwkbz]